# jQuery getJSON Undefined Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Alright, so I've done a bit of searching and trying with no luck. I'm hoping that someone here can point me in the right direction. I have a JSON feed that I'm working with, which is supposed to output a variety of data. Currently, it just sends back and "UNDEFINED" response for all variables. Here is the JS I'm using:

```
$("#loaduserdata").click(function(){
$("#userdata tbody").html("");
    $.getJSON("trendFetch", function(data){
            $.each(data.list, function(i, data){
                var jsondata = data.action;
                console.log (jsondata);
            });
     }
);
```

I'm not sure where the problem exists, because console isn't giving me any kind of errors or any reason to think that the JSON isn't formatted correctly: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEEuo.png

For whatever it's worth, here is the code I'm using to generate the JSON - maybe there is an issue on that end?

```
$curl = curl_init();
$url = 'http://api.site.com';

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url
));

$resp = curl_exec($curl);

if($resp){
    echo $resp;
    header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
}
else {
    echo 'Error - no response!';
}

curl_close($curl);
```

EDIT - including JSON output:

```
{
"status": "ok",
"list": {
    "list_id": "2gz",
    "title": "Test List",
    "description": "description text...",
    "image": [
        "http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTz6_4aV6oHsI2kgJRRoSFCTWbew5ChTeBrAmXYh4Gez2J7usm8nwMOsA",
        "http://cdn.list.ly/logos/default-list-image.png"
    ],
    "views": 0,
    "item_count": 1,
    "curator_count": 1,
    "follower_count": 1,
    "listly_url": "http://api.list.ly/list/2gz-test-list",
    "items": [
        {
            "item": {
                "name": "Link 1",
                "image": "http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTz6_4aV6oHsI2kgJRRoSFCTWbew5ChTeBrAmXYh4Gez2J7usm8nwMOsA",
                "note": null,
                "url": null,
                "likes": 0,
                "dislikes": 0
            }
        }
    ],
    "suggested_items": []
}
}
```

Comment: Why I think the first 2 lines of Javascript is nonsense?

Comment: Your right, I cleaned that up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the header before any output

```
header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
echo $resp;
```

Comment: As I mentioned to Cryptic I think the problem is unrelated to the PHP because when I view the JSON in console it looks good. Any other ideas?

Comment: @viablepath yeah, I just saw the image, can you post the JSON as text though.

Comment: Sure, I just added it to the original post. Thanks!

Comment: @viablepath there is no action property anywhere in the JSON response, what are you trying to do with what data?

Comment: I simply want to append it to a div and display it on my site. Not sure what you mean by no action property - sorry?

Comment: @viablepath what did you expect to get with `data.action`

Comment: At the end of the day, I want to extract the list name. I had some code that was doing it, but removed it in an effort to work backwards and find my problem.

Comment: @viablepath do you mean like `Link 1`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21586/discussion-between-viablepath-and-musa)

Answer (score 4):

```
echo $resp;
header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
```

should be:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
echo $resp;
```

You need to send HTTP headers before you output any content.

Comment: I made the change as you requested, but unfortunately it did not solve the issue. Regardless thanks for the tip, it needed to be formatted properly anyway.

Comment: @viablepath what is on line 64 of application.js?

Comment: Line 64 = console.log (jsondata);

Answer (score 0):

It'd help if you provided the JSON response.

When I'm having these types of issues, I typically take a step back (in the code) and `console.log()` earlier. For example, `console.log(data)` within the `function(data) {}`.

I think -- from looking at the output -- that your problem is that list isn't actually a list. data.list is, in fact, an object. Therefore `.each()` will iterate over the individual items (like list_id, title, etc). None of these have a `.action` property.

I can't see any action property, so I can't make a solution suggestion. It's possible that it's within the list object -- but you're still treating it like an array (as if it's `list: [{}, {}]` rather than `list: {}`). In this case, you either need to fix the returned JSON or get rid of the `$.each()`, and just `console.log(data.list.action)`.

Comment: I just added the JSON response to the original post. This is what I got when I added a console.log to the function(data): http://i.imgur.com/hXzcz.png

Comment: Yeah. See the last paragrah that I added. It's still true with the JSON response you posted. .action (which you're trying to access with `data.action`) doesn't exist. You should describe what you want the result to be.

Comment: I want to pull out a few variables from the list array (list_id, title, description) and display them in a table.

Answer (score 0):

Musa was able to solve this for me, so in case someone Googles, the problem was that I was trying to use $.each when I didn't need to. Here is the correct code in case anyone is interested:

```
$.getJSON("trendFetch",function(data){
                var tblRow =
                    "<tr>"
                    +"<td>"+data.list.list_id+"</td>"
                    +"<td>"+data.list.title+"</td>"
                    +"<td>"+data.list.description+"</td>"
                    +"</tr>"
                $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");

        }
);
```